# getting specific x items from list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get specific x items from a list I created.

```
List<Item> il = (List<Item>)(from i in AllItems
                             where i.Iid == item.Iid
                             select i).Take(Int32.Parse(item.amount));
```

I get the following error:

> "Unable to cast object of type 'd__3a`1[AssetManagement.Entities.Item]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AssetManagement.Entities.Item]'."

How can it be fixed and why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the ".ToList()" call at the end as KingKing correctly pointed out. Without that, that query will result in an IQueryable that cannot be cast to List.

As a side node, I'd prefer using implicit variable type declaration, like

```
var il = (from i in AllItems
    where i.Iid == item.Iid
    select i).Take(Int32.Parse(item.amount)).ToList();
```

This way, it wouldn't have thrown an exception even without the "ToList" (but maybe it wouldn't have been what you expected)

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Item> il = (from i in AllItems
                 where i.Iid == item.Iid
                 select i).Take(Int32.Parse(item.amount)).ToList();
```

**NOTE**: Casting can be done only between objects with the `Inheritance` or `Implementation` relationship. Try to remember that.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this syntax more readable? (The only difference from your query is the `ToList()`)

```
List<Item> il = AllItems.Where(i => i.Iid == item.Iid)
                        .Take(Int32.Parse(item.amount))
                        .ToList();
```

I never liked using parentheses to materialize the query `(from..where..select).ToList();`

Comment: you can merge the `Where` and the `Take` with a [`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile.aspx)

Comment: @Default I am not sure. The items may not be at the beginning of the enumeration.